# Age of majority in Washington state in 1945?

Tags: 20th-century, 1940s, washington-state

What was the age of majority in Washington state in 1945?

Comment: It is unclear what does this mean "age of majority".

Comment: @Alex Washington state made the definition clear in their legislation (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the legal "age of majority" in Washington state was 21 from 1854 until 1971, when it was amended by [House Bill No. 309](http://leg.wa.gov/CodeReviser/documents/sessionlaw/1971ex1c292.pdf?cite=1971%20ex.s.%20c%20292%20%C2%A7%201;) and became 18.

---

There are different definitions of the term "[age of majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority)". In this case, the "age of majority" is defined in the bill as follows:

> ... all persons shall be deemed and taken to be of full age for all
>   purposes

---

So, to answer your question, **the age of majority in Washington state in 1945 was 21**.